# Combine two mysql tables with companies and contacts

Tags: mysql, select

i have two tables in `mysql`. The first one holds companies and the second one holds contacts that work for these companies.

There are companies without contacts, and there are several contacts that can work for one company, but there are never contacts without a company.

The tables look like this:

company table

```
company_id
company_name
company_telephone
```

contacts table

```
contact_id
works_for_company_id
contact_fullname
contact_telephone
```

I am trying to combine both tables with one select statement in order to create a list of telephone numbers for each and every entry, e. g. one company with two contacts results in three entries, each with the company name and telephone number in one row.

I tried JOIN statements, which all resulted in displaying the contacts but not the companies behind it, i tried UNION (didn't work because of different column names). What else am I missing? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: A `JOIN` is exactly what you would use for this.  What did you try and how did it fail?

Comment: Please share your query attempt(s) with us if possible.  A join or a union are basically your only options to bring two tables together.

Comment: Updated Answer Please check

Answer (score 1):

You combine both join and union - but you will have to rename the differently named columns (via `AS`):

```
SELECT company_id, company_telephone AS phone FROM company
UNION
SELECT company_id, contact_telephone AS phone FROM company JOIN contacts ON ...
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need is direct straight join to get all the details. You can replace * with relevant column names:

```
SELECT *
FROM CONTACTS_TABLE con
JOIN COMPANY_TABLE cta ON cta.company_id = con.works_for_company_id
```

Comment: I tried your solution.  Your solution does not deliver the company record, e.g. ONE company with TWO contacts should result in THREE result rows.

Answer (score 0):

As people told you in previous comments, you need a **join/inner join**

```
SELECT comp.company_id, cont.contact_fullname
    FROM company comp
    INNER JOIN contacts cont ON comp.company_id = cont.works_for_company_id;
```

Comment: Your solution does not deliver the company record, e.g. ONE company with TWO contacts should result in THREE rows.

Answer (score 0):

### The UNION operator is used to combine the result-set of two or more SELECT statements.

- Each SELECT statement within UNION must have the same number of
  columns
- The columns must also have similar data types
- The columns in each SELECT statement must also be in the same order

  SELECT  `company`.`company_name`, `company`.`company_telephone` 
  FROM  `company` 
  WHERE  `company.company_id` =1
  UNION 
  SELECT  `contact`.`contact_fullname`, `contact`.`contact_fullname` 
  FROM  `company` 
  JOIN  `contact` ON  `company`.`company_id` =  `contact`.`works_for_company_id` 
  WHERE  `company`.`company_id` =1
  LIMIT 0 , 30

Comment: Your solution shows all contacts with their company details but does not include the company itself. E. g. one company with two contacts should result in three rows.

Answer (score 0):

*There are companies without contacts*  SO you need to use `LEFT JOIN`

```
SELECT com.company_name,com.telephone ,com.company_id, con.contact_fullname
FROM company com
LEFT JOIN contacts con ON com.company_id = con.works_for_company_id;
```

Comment: I tried your solution. Your solution results in all companies that do not have any contacts associated (very good) and companies that do have contacts associated (also good). But what I need is an additional row for each company even if there are contacts associated, for example: one company with two contacts results in 3 rows. So that i can use the main telephone number of the company itself and the two individual telephone numbers of each contact.